# auto increment on column type in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id  animal      type    value

1   Dog           Land  11
2   Fish        Water   102
3   Horse       Land    12
4   Duck        Water   104
5   Crocodile   Water   105
6   Donkey      Land    13
7   Buffalo     Land    14
```

how to increase the value if one more record is inserted when type=land it will increase to 15
and

one more record is inserted when type=water it will increase to 106
please let me know

Comment: Are you using any programming language along with `mysql`?

Comment: no  am not using

Comment: Ok, then how are you inserting these values? Are you getting this from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't materialize that. That bears a severe risk that the data becomes inconsistent. Use a view getting the count in a subquery.

```
ALTER TABLE elbat
            DROP value;

CREATE VIEW elbat_with_value
AS
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.animal,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.id <= t1.id
                     AND t2.type = t1.type) value
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Or in MySQL version 8 you could use `row_number()`.

```
ALTER TABLE elbat
            DROP value;

CREATE VIEW elbat_with_value
AS
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.animal,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITON BY t1.type
                          ORDER BY t1.id) value
       FROM elbat t1;
```